# How to separate surds or integers from mixed quadratic surds?

Tags: number-representation, format

If I have a number of the form:

$$a + \sqrt{b}$$

How can I get $$a  \text{ or } \sqrt{b}$$ by itself?

For example,

```
GetSurdPart[HoldForm[977+Sqrt[56]]] -> Sqrt[56]
GetIntegerPart[HoldForm[977+Sqrt[56]]] -> 977

First[List@@(a+Sqrt[b])] -> a

Last[List@@(a+Sqrt[b])] -> Sqrt[b]
```

The last two work, but only if symbolic. I cannot use HoldForm without first finding the surd using those two methods.

Comment: `Sqrt[56]` auto-simplifies to `2 Sqrt[14]` -- I guess that's ok?

Comment: @MichaelE2 The problem is no. Because I am trying to find an explicit formula for a certain sequence of mixed quadratic surds. If it is evaluated, it makes it more difficult for a human like me to recognize or think about patterns. The formula for the integer parts will be different than the one for the surds.

Comment: How do you get the data? In particular, if `977 + Sqrt[56]` is generated in some way, how do you keep `Sqrt[56]` from evaluating to `2 Sqrt[14]`? If you do something to block the evaluation of `Sqrt` or `Power`, it might be easier to generate `{977, 56}` instead. Or if you're reading data from a file, it might be easier to parse the file. -- In any case, one cannot be given a number in the form `977 + Sqrt[56]` in Mma unless it is unevaluated and not allowed to evaluate. It is difficult to prevent evaluation unless the expression is in a different form, either using `Hold` or `Inactive`.

Comment: I'd ask for more information about your larger objective and the actual data you're working with, including its form/structure. Your comment above is pointing in the right direction--can you provide more? The problem, as I'm sure you've already noticed and are struggling with, is that MMA has no real concept of surd (even the symbol Surd immediately resolves to something using Power). MMA has no idea that surd is important to you as part of the structure of a quantity. You're probably going to need to inject that semantic yourself.

Comment: So, for example, you can use a new symbol of your own choosing to represent the notion of surd. It would just hold its contents and allow you to recognize it, pattern match on it, and choose when to perform calculations on it. If the "sequence of mixed quadratic surds" is something you have control over, then instead of using Sqrt or Surd, just use MySurd (or whatever). MySurd can be made to display however you want and can also be made to evaluate to an actual Sqrt/Surd at the moment of your choosing.

Comment: @MichaelE2 The purpose of me doing this is to help find me the strictly increasing sequence of mixed quadratic surds using only positive integers. I am trying to find an explicit formula to do that. And I think I will be able to do one for the surd part soon, the integer part is difficult. This is the question I am working on: [Finding Ordered Sequence of Subset of Mixed Quadratic Surds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4665125/sequence-of-quadratic-surds-over-nonnegative-integers-without-having-to-delete-o/4665251#4665251). It is ambitious I guess.

Comment: @lericr Now I am using it for the purpose that I described to Michael. But I remember a long time ago I had to find it before for a completely unrelated math problem. (I think it was trying to take generalized aliquot sequences and treating them as continued fractions. Then finding the corresponding mixed quadratic surd.) I just had a feeling that MMA had a specific command for finding it but I couldn't find it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define some patterns to match, for splitting a number into an integer part and a surd part:

```
p[a_Integer] = {a, 0};
p[a_. + u_. Sqrt[b_Integer]] = {a, u^2 b};
```

For extracting these components, we have to [defer](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Defer.html) the `Sqrt`:

```
GetIntegerPart[z_] := p[z][[1]]
GetSurdPart[z_] := Defer[Sqrt][p[z][[2]]]
```

Tests:

```
GetIntegerPart /@ {6, Sqrt[2], Sqrt[8], 6 + Sqrt[2], 6 + Sqrt[8]}
(*    {6, 0, 0, 6, 6}    *)

GetSurdPart /@ {6, Sqrt[2], Sqrt[8], 6 + Sqrt[2], 6 + Sqrt[8]}
(*    {Sqrt[0], Sqrt[2], Sqrt[8], Sqrt[2], Sqrt[8]}    *)
```

Comment: Your answer is super nice and amazing. I didn't know about defer. I regret taking such a long pause using Mathematica nice. It also has an aesthetic output for the format versus Inactive.

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

expr = 977 + Sqrt[56];
```

The expression does not need to be a [`List`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html) to use [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html)

```
expr[[1]]

(* 977 *)

expr[[2]]

(* 2 Sqrt[14] *)

Inactive[Sqrt][expr[[2]]^2]
```

[image]

```
% // Activate

(* 2 Sqrt[14] *)
```

Answer (score 2):

For numbers you can write

```
Cases[2 + Sqrt[5] , _Integer][[1]]
Cases[2 + Sqrt[5] , _Power][[1]]

2
Sqrt[5]
```

Or with a rational:

```
Cases[1/2 + Sqrt[5] , _Rational][[1]]

1/2
```

For Symbols:

```
Cases[a + Sqrt[b] , _Symbol][[1]]
Cases[a + Sqrt[b] , _Power][[1]]

a
Sqrt[b]
```

If your number contains a machine number like e.g. 2., then the expression is evaluated instantaneously and the structure is lost.